# How to increase time of holding buttons to take screen shot on Samsung Note 8

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, screenshots, keyboard-shortcuts

I have looked around online and not found an answer since the question seems too specific! My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 8.

I find that even a quick accidental press of volume down and power button causes a screenshot (this seems to happen a lot more often than one would expect). Is there any way to increase the time one would need to hold the buttons down in order to take the screenshot?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't if it is possible to increase the length of time it takes to capture screenshots using buttons.

However, since you get unwanted screenshots when using the buttons, I advise you try using other methods that your device is capable of.

A method that may help you is to use your hand to swipe and take a screenshot.

1. Goto Settings -> Advanced features -> Enable "Palm swipe to capture".
2. Open the app you want to capture.
3. Swipe the whole screen with the side of your hand.